# Can't delete records from the same table using NOT EXISTS MySQL syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to perform deletion in the same table. I've tried different ways, but I still can't get it right. So, I got this error **You can't specify target table 'tb' for update in FROM clause**. I tried aliasing the tables, but nothing done. I can't figure out what is missing. I appreciate any ideas.

```
 DELETE FROM tb WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tb t WHERE t.`merchantId` = 'A32WNPGI8GE4WW' AND t.`marketplaceId` IN ('A1AM78C64UM0Y8', 'A2EUQ1WTGCTBG2', 'ATVPDKIKX0DER'));
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Sqlite? You tagged both...

Comment: @Shawn That was my bad. I'm using MySQL. Have you got any ideas about what's wrong?

Comment: Yep, see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry I think this is what did. I provide a sample code snippet to show what I'm trying to achieve. Is there something wrong about that?

Comment: Your subquery isn't correlated. I.e. if it worked, it would delete everything from the table once there were no rows satisfying the subquery. Is that intentional?

Comment: @stickybit thanks for your answer. My goal is to delete everything from table "tb", except what is in the subquery. The subquery statement should still exist after deletion.

Comment: Well, it's best to follow the advice of @Strawberry and provide a [example] to clarify what you have and want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL supports `JOIN`s in `DELETE` and `UPDATE`.  This works around the "same table" limitation in this database.  For your logic, it could look like:

```
DELETE tb
    FROM tb LEFT JOIN
         tb tb2
         ON tb2.`merchantId` = 'A32WNPGI8GE4WW' AND
            tb2.`marketplaceId` IN ('A1AM78C64UM0Y8', 'A2EUQ1WTGCTBG2', 'ATVPDKIKX0DER')
    WHERE tb2.merchantID IS NULL;
```

This query is highly irregular, though.  It is either deleting *all* rows or no rows.

If you just want to keep those rows, then this is the way to go:

```
DELETE tb FROM tb
    WHERE NOT (tb.`merchantId` = 'A32WNPGI8GE4WW' AND
               tb.`marketplaceId` IN ('A1AM78C64UM0Y8', 'A2EUQ1WTGCTBG2', 'ATVPDKIKX0DER')
              );
```

Or:

```
DELETE tb FROM tb
    WHERE tb.merchantId <> 'A32WNPGI8GE4WW' OR
          tb.marketplaceId NOT IN ('A1AM78C64UM0Y8', 'A2EUQ1WTGCTBG2', 'ATVPDKIKX0DER');
```

If there are `NULL` values in either column, then the logic also needs to take this into account.

Comment: thanks a lot for providing different and clear ways for doing this.

Answer (score 2):

for avoid the update error   when operating on same  table you could try using a nested subquery for build a temp table

```
 DELETE  FROM tb 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
    SELECT * 
    FROM (
      SELECT * 
      from tb
      WHERE `merchantId` = 'A32WNPGI8GE4WW' 
      AND `marketplaceId`  IN ('A1AM78C64UM0Y8', 'A2EUQ1WTGCTBG2', 'ATVPDKIKX0DER')
    ) t
  );
```